# Why do I get an error message when the user is asked to enter a char?

Tags: java

```
private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static char[] board = new char[9];
private static boolean[] isAvail = new boolean[9];
private static char currentPlayer = ' ';
private static char playAgain = ' ';

// *******************************************************
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!!");
    System.out.print("Would you like to play a game? (enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no): ");

    do {
    char play = ' ';
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        isAvail[i] = false;

    play = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0); 

    System.out.println();

    if (play != 'y') {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    playGame();

    playAgain = ' ';
    System.out.print("Would you like to play another game (enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no): ");
    //String space = keyboard.nextLine();
    playAgain = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0); 


    }while(playAgain == 'y');

    System.out.println("Goodbye!");

}
```

I am doing a tic-tac-toe program with many methods. In this method there is the do-while loop which asks the user if they'd like to play the game and then after the game is complete if they'd like to play again. When I take out the String space = keyboard.nextLine(); line I get an error message, but when I have it in the user has to type y twice to play again. How can I fix this to only type y once to play again? Thanks

Example:

```
Would you like to play another game (enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no): 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at TicTacToeMihalovich.main(TicTacToeMihalovich.java:37)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks was just adding it into the question when you asked, its in now.

Comment: You probably don't want to call `nextLine()` twice.

Comment: @SLaks its the only way to not get the error message

Comment: Do you call `keyboard.nextInt()` or similar in `playGame()`?

Comment: What do you have in line 37? Exception says -  `at TicTacToeMihalovich.main(TicTacToeMihalovich.java:37)`

Comment: Line 37 is printing Goodbye

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `char play = ' ';` and go ahead with `playAgain`.

```
System.out.println("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!!");
System.out.print("Would you like to play a game? (enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no): ");



do {
    playAgain = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);


    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        isAvail[i] = false;


    System.out.println();

    if (playAgain != 'y') {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    playGame();



    //playAgain = ' ';
    System.out.print("Would you like to play another game (enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no): ");
    //String space = keyboard.nextLine();
    //playAgain = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);


} while(playAgain == 'y');

System.out.println("Goodbye!");

}
```